# Оптимизация sql-запроса с подзапросами

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, оптимизация-запросов

Есть запрос, в котором участвуют несколько подзапросов с одной и той же таблицей, но разными `where`. Можно ли это как-то оптимизировать?

Дополнительная информация:
Структуру базы данных не могу менять
СУБД MySQL

```
SELECT cr.id as id, cp.brand, cp.model, cr.cat_number, ..., 
       (SELECT name FROM catalogue_property WHERE id=cr.width) as width,
       (SELECT name FROM catalogue_property WHERE id=cr.height) as height,            
       (SELECT name FROM catalogue_groups_description WHERE cat_group_id=cr.group_id) as radius,
       (SELECT wb_export FROM wi_exp WHERE items=cr.id) as wb_export
              FROM catalogue_relationship cr
              JOIN (catalogue_products cp,catalogue_groups cg,catalogue_groups_description gd) 
        ON (cp.item_id = cr.id AND cg.id = cr.group_id 
        AND gd.cat_group_id = cr.group_id)
        WHERE cr.public=1 
GROUP BY cr.id
ORDER BY cr.id ASC
```

Comment: А что сейчас не устраивает в производительности?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, Возможно есть лучшие способы объединение таблиц. На все поля, участвующие в объединениях и фильтрации есть индекс. Хотелось выжать максимально с этого запроса.

Comment: Сейчас MySQL поумнел и такие запросы хорошо сам оптимизирует, но  сделай EXPLAIN  запроса, мб что-то будет интересное

Comment: Подзапросы к `catalogue_property` не выглядят неоптимальными, т.к. выбирают данные по разным ключам. И если столбец `id` индексированный, то улучшать их не надо - попытка "оптимизации" приведёт к обратному эффекту :)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ зависит конечно от результата выборки.

1. Если у вас результат не большой, не не вижу смысла что либо менять.
   Запрос у вас и так не должен долго работать.
2. Если у вас результат большой, то можете соединить справочники на
   join. Соединить один раз справочник по индексированному ключу лучше
   нежели бегать каждый раз и находить конкретный.

Comment: Запрос в 3000 строк однако таблица большая. Также таблица часто изменяется. Запрос практически всегда выполняется без лимитов с интервалом среднем около 10 секунд ( разными клиентами). Кэшировать не выйдет - важны актуальные данные. Также интересный факт, когда был на старом сервере обычные запросы он выполнял медленнее, но вот сложные выполняет в два раза быстрее. Возможно дело в настройке базы какой-то? Конфигурацию уже не смогу сравнить